# All products bought by a particular user

Tags: sql

I have two tables:
x_products

```
id    name    image  price
--  -------  ------  -----
1    name1    path     10
2    name2    path      8
3    name3    NULL      7
4    name4    path     10
5    name5    path      5
```

**x_user_products**

```
id  userId  productId
--  ------  --------- 
1     100      1     
2     100      2
3     105      1
4     105      3
5     100      5
6     102      2
```

how to SELECT all product of a user (for example user 100) in x_products?
the result should be like this:

```
id    name    image  price
--  -------  ------  -----
1    name1    path     10
2    name2    path      8
5    name5    path      5
```

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: Also provide expected results as formatted text based on the example data.. What should happen when a user has the same products for example two productId 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the **INNER JOIN** keyword which selects records that have matching values in both tables.

[image: Inner Join]

The code:

```
SELECT xp.*
FROM x_products xp
INNER JOIN x_user_products xup ON xp.id = xup.productId
WHERE xup.userId = 100
```

Answer (score 0):

You appears to want :

```
select xp.*
from x_products xp
where exists (select 1 
              from x_user_products xup 
              where xup.productId = xp.id and xup.userId = 100);
```